# Parsing json object in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I'm using `System.Net.Json.JsonTextParser` to parse json files while developing program in C#, so I setup the `col` object like following according to the tutorial:

```
JsonTextParser parser = new JsonTextParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file));
JsonObjectCollection col = (JsonObjectCollection)obj;
```

And in this case, I know I can get value of a key(for example, `"formats"`) like following:

```
string Data = Convert.ToString(col["formats"].GetValue());
```

However, how can I read another json object under a key? Sorry I don't know how to express this, but, for example, I have:

```
"formats" : {"key1" : "value11", "key2" : "value12"}, {"key1" : "value21", "key2" : "value22"}
```

and what should I do to get each json object under `"formats"`? How to read each value of `"key1"`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you use Json.NET?

Comment: Just a suggestion, Newtonsoft JSON.NET https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm is probably a better library for dealing with JSON and I think you are more likely to get help using it.

Comment: Is that the actual json youre trying to parse as jsonlint gives me Error: Parse error on line 1:
"formats": { "key1": "value1
---------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

Comment: @CodeWarrior No that's just an example so it can have error

Comment: no, it cant, if you want help on code, then youve got to give us something that compiles and that youre working with so that we can help you. Its like giving me a pork sausage and asking me to make you a beef burger out of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

you should create a c# class coressponding your json file.

for your json file it would be:

```
public class Formats
{
    public string Key1 {get; set;}
    public string Key2 {get; set;}
}
```

and then convert your json file to c# objects:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("file.json"))
{
    string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Formats>>(json);
    foreach( var obj in jsonObject )
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key1: {obj.Key1}, Key2: {obj.Key2}");
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I have more keys under subkeys, I can values like `obj.key1.key2.key3....`??

Comment: you can do anything you want with the c# object and yes nested objects are supported.